# Condition on pipeline Stage execution not working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to set a condition on executing a stage in my yml file(build pipeline).

The condition is that the repo name must contain "application" keyword, if not the stage need to be ignored;

my code is like this

```
- stage: deploy
  condition: contains(variables['Build.Repository.Name'],'application')
  dependsOn: build
  jobs:
   - template: deploy-snapshot-jobs.yml@pipelines-templates
```

It don't work like this, I think the interpreter don't replace variables['Build.Repository.Name'] with the repository name because when I use literal value of repo name it work fine

any help how can get this working guys ?

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue, I tried with the condition and the stage skipped. (I don't use a template, maybe it's related?)

Comment: If the repo name contain 'application'  stage will be skipped also, you can change 'application' by whatever your repo name contain, will be skipped, can you confirm ?

Comment: this is working variables['Build.DefinitionName']

Comment: My mistake! the stage skipped even my repo contains the word I put in the condition.

Comment: @AnouarBAKRI, Hi, how the things going? Does my answer could help you resolve your issue? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)

Comment: @Anouar BAKRI Did you try out Frank's solution? Any good news?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT finaly I used variables['Build.DefinitionName'] variable instead of variables['Build.Repository.Name'] as it contain the same value

Answer (score 1):

You can change the confition to effect your task not stage. For example, first I set the YAML file as below.
[image]

The Deploy stage will not queue and you can see some differences in the log.
[image]

The Deploy stage doesn't have the preparation stage before task. If the stage didn't checkout the git source, the Build.Repository.Name value will be null. That is why your deploy stage will not queue.
Because the different stage meaning different environment and agent, so the agent-scoped variable value need to be obtained again in different stages. The Build.Repository.Name is an agent-scoped variable, you can refe to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables.

When I edit the YAML file as below.
[image]

The Deploy stage will run as expected. 
[image]

And if the repository name is not matched the condition, the error log is as below.
[image]